# Too Much time taken by phpmailer library

Tags: performance, email, gmail, phpmailer, attachment

I am creating a script to send 10 files to different recipients daily basis. These files size can be upto 15 MB. The phpmailer is taking lot of time 10 to 15 min. so it become unusable to me. I am using gmail smtp.

```
//Server settings
//$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //Alternative to above constant
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'rmudelhi@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'rainfall2016';                               // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->SMTPSecure= 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

Can someone help me to improve this?

Comment: Could you please post your code which sends the email?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that PHPMailer is slow, it's that you're trying to perform an inherently slow operation during page load; you're transferring around 150 megabytes *per recipient*, which is never going to happen quickly.

Do not do the email sending during the page load - save the fact that you need to do the send in your database or queue, and process the send asynchronously.

The easiest way to do this is to use a cron job to pick up the send tasks and run them.

Alternatively, do not send the files by email, but send a message containing links that point at them, so that the recipients can download them via HTTP more efficiently. Email is simply not an efficient method for sending large files.